# Logitech brio 4K mode only works on its own cable?

Tags: windows-10, 4k-resolution, usb-c, logitech-webcam

I got a Logitech Brio camera and wanted to set up for 4K video. 
However, somehow the 4K mode was recognized by the windows only with the original usb-c to usb 3.0 cable sent through the box.

I tried a usb-c to usb-c cable and usb-c to usb 3.0 cable by amazon. The windows was able to recognize it as a HD camera, but not a 4K one.

Why Logitech brio 4K mode only works on its own cable? Which kind of cable are compatible with Logitech brio 4K mode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I've done some testing using a MacBook Pro 2017. All tests were performed using  OBS 27.1.0 and Brio with Firmware 2.0.28, EEPROM 1.18 and Sensor 5.5

Observations:

1. Using cheap USB-C to USB-C cables limit the camera to MJPEG on 1080p/30f.
2. Using the Logitech supplied cable and an Anker USB-C to USB 3.1 adaptor (AK-848061067804) I can get 2160p/30f MJPEG and 1080p/30f NV12
3. Using good quality cables (e.g. Anker USB-c to USB3 / AK-A8169091) gives the same result as 2.
4. Using a 10Gbit certified USB-C to USB-C cable (e.g. Cable Matters 10gbit 1m ASIN:B01L0F6AJI) on both 10gbit or 5gbit USB-C ports will allow for 4k video with nv12.

Conclusion:

If you want NV12 **or** 4k resolution you need a quality usb3 cable that supports data rates at 480mbps.

If you need 4k **and** nv12 use a 5gbit/10gbit certified USB-C to USB-C cable.

Comment: I have tried many USB-C cables; by Anker / Ugreen and I cannot get any to provide 4k performance. Maybe some weird shielding issue. Works perfectly with the logitech cable; but the design of that cable leaves a lot to be desired for my requirement.

Comment: Make sure the cable supports data rates >  480mbps

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will try and get one...

Comment: I lost my Brio cable and this answer saved me! I got an Ugreen US184 cable and it worked!

Comment: Is a 10 gbit/s cable really necessary or would a 4.8 gbit/s cable be sufficient?

Comment: 4.8gbit should be enough. Will test later tonight.